# A few general questions about creating browser extensions

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, browser-addons

1. I want to create an image slider (toggleable from the toolbar) and overlay it over the top of the browser window so that it kind of hangs above all websites you visit.  What forms is this possible? (e.g. forms which change the html of pages or not)
2. Is it possible to do the same thing with things such as a jquery grid or other controls like radcontrols (ajax)?
3. If you can include a jqgrid, can you have it work as if it were on your website by communicating via api?
4. When internet explorer becomes addonphobic, will this mean extensions unsupported too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to build this extension on all browsers and not just one I would really recommend checking out [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com).

With Crossrider you can develop extensions to all (major) browsers - Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox and Safari with only JavaScript!

The beauty about this is that as you are looking to use the jqgrid jQuery plugin in your extension you are going to find that Crossrider has a built-in jQuery support to make the integration seamless.

To toggle the plugin on/off from the browser's UI you can simply use browserAction.onClick:

```
appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {      
  // toggle jqgrid
});
```

Comment: Awesome, any input in terms of the overlay idea or other points at all? I think I will probably be developing using the radcontrols ajax library